# Calculated site columns/Lookup site columns - cannot add calculated numeric fields

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, calculated-column, site-column

I have a list with broken down data that is aggregated to some kind of combined ID data format that references a certain file. (Say, there is a file called 123-1. I have a field then that stores "123" and another one that stores "1"). I also have a column that calculates some kind of numeric data field based on these columns in the list.

Example:

> Prefix     Core       Suffix       Combined 
>   123        123        123          369

"Combined" is the column of interest of this post...

However, to my dismay, as I tried adding this column as a site column, it did not work. It appears that site columns cannot be added if the field is a number calculated field. Is that correct? Or did I miss something?

I also tried, maybe I can just create a calculated site column to make this work instead. But apparently, I cannot seem to reference any lookup site column in my calculated site column formulae when I tried creating a calculated site column.

Ultimately, I am trying to use the site column as a way to transfer data from a parent site to some child sites. I tried going with the approach of recreating all the data needed to calculate what I need in the child site, but I run into the same problem that the lookup column based on a site column in a child site is not allowed to be used in a calculated column within that list I created in the child site.

Any suggestions on a workaround? Thanks!!

Comment: Lookup fields cannot be referenced in the calculated columns. You will need workflow to update fields. See this if this meets your requirements: https://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/utilize-lookup-column-in-calculated-column-sharepoint-list-libraries/

Comment: I was delighted when I saw this, and thought it is going to solve the worlds' problems! But I am wrong... This works for the primary site column but does not work for other associated columns. Taking our sample table up there, It works for the 369 that was set as a site column, but it did not work for the 123 that was also designated as available for use. Thanks!